# Different alignment of widgets in QGridLayout

Tags: qt, alignment, qlayout, qgridlayout

The following code (**Qt 5**, same behaviour with Qt 4.8) uses a `QGridLayout` to add widgets above and to the left of a `QScrollArea` (to serve as a kind of header later):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>

class ColoredWidget : public QWidget {
public:
    ColoredWidget(const  QColor& color, QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {
        QPalette pal;
        QBrush brush(color);
        brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
        pal.setBrush(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Window, brush);
        setPalette(pal);
        setAutoFillBackground(true);
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        resize(300, 400);

        QWidget* centralwidget = new ColoredWidget(QColor(0xff, 0xf0, 0xb5), this);

        QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
        centralwidget->setLayout(layout);
        setCentralWidget(centralwidget);

        // create widget with fixed height of 20 px and maximum width of 200
        QWidget* topHeader = new ColoredWidget(Qt::green, centralwidget);
        topHeader->setMaximumWidth(200);
        topHeader->setFixedHeight(20);

        // create widget with fixed width of 20 px and maximum height of 200
        QWidget* leftHeader = new ColoredWidget(Qt::blue, centralwidget);
        leftHeader->setFixedWidth(20);
        leftHeader->setMaximumHeight(200);

        // create scroll area as main widget
        QWidget* view = new QScrollArea();

        layout->addWidget(topHeader,  0, 1);
        layout->addWidget(leftHeader, 1, 0);
        // layout->addWidget(leftHeader, 1, 0, Qt::AlignTop); // widget not displayed at all!
        layout->addWidget(view, 1, 1);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    MainWindow win(0);
    win.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The `QGridLayout` documentation says that "Columns and rows behave identically", thus I would expect that the two widgets are layouted the same way.

However, the left one is automatically **vertically centered**, while the top widget is **aligned to the left** within the cell (and **not** centered horizontally). I would like to have the left widget also at a fixed position, means aligned to the top:

[image: Strange Layout]

- Which property causes this different behaviour between the two widgets, one beeing **centered**, the other being at a **fixed position**?
- How can I influence the alignment (I can probably add a flexible spacer to fix it, but ideally I would like to avoid that)? I tried with `Qt::AlignTop`, but that made the blue widget disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not a minimal solution you could probably fix the alignments by adding a `QHBoxLayout` in the cell for the green widget and a `QVBoxLayout` in the cell for the blue widget. Add the green widget to the `QHBoxLayout` and the blue widget to the `QVBoxLayout`. Then apply `addStretch(n)` to both the `QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout`. Maybe this is what you already mentioned you could do and then we are at the same level of knowledge concerning this. I believe this is the way I have solved these kind of issues and I haven't spent more time on it.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the alignment  either with:

```
layout->setAlignment(leftHeader, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
```

or with:

```
layout->addWidget(leftHeader, 1, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
```

is intuitive and seems to be the right way. If it is setup completely it is also working as expected.

**But why does the Widget vanish then?**
Long story short: because leftHeader has a size of 0.

In my pretty similar situation I've `setfixedHeight()` and the widget reappeared, this should also work by setting a value for `minimalHeight()` for example.

**Long Story - Details**
I've put myself in position of gridLayout and tried to determine the size of `leftHeader`:

1. Outside of the layout `leftHeader` got a fixed width of 20 - ok, but no given height.
    With the defaults of QWidget this leads to a default-height of 0.
2. Documentation of `void QGridLayout::addWidget()` and `void QGridLayout::addLayout()` states:

> ... 
>  The alignment is specified by alignment. The default alignment is
> 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell. 
> ...

[source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1)

Hence for default alignment of 0 the height of `leftHeader` is obviously set as height of its row.
But in case a different `Qt::Alignment` is used, as in the question (`Qt::AlignTop` ), it is not that simple.

From my point of view the layout is unable to determine the correct height without further settings from the designer.

Having a quick look at the implementation of `void QGridLayout::addWidget()`, we can detect that a `QLayoutItem`(as part of `QGridBox`) is created inside the `QGridLayout` for each added widget resp. Layout.
So it seems that the `QGridLayout` relies on default layout mechanisms of Qt based on the settings from the added widget/Layout (like `minSize`, `maxSize`, `BaseSize`, `Size Increment`, etc ).

In combination with *1.)* this implies a height of 0 for `leftHeader` and therefore nothing to draw resp. it seems that the widget has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop );
```

Comment: You mean `layout->setAlignment(leftHeader, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);` to set the alignment of the blue widget? That makes the blue widget invisible ...